Reading GPD serial port in C# gives me random text
Trying to read GPS device location using code below:
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;


public class Program
{


    public static SerialPort? _serialPort;
    public static SerialPort? _serialPort_gps;
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Crete an excel Name: Seriel_PORT_READING + DDMMYYYHHMMSS 
        for (int i = 1; i<= 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);        
            DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Current Reading Time: " + currentDateTime);

            // Create a new SerialPort object
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();
            _serialPort_gps = new SerialPort();


            // Set the port name (COM1, COM2, etc.)
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM4";
            // _serialPort_gps.PortName = "COM4";


            // Set baud rate
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;

            // Set parity (none, odd, even, mark, space)
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;

            // Set data bits
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;

            // Set stop bits (one, two, or more)
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            // Set handshake (none, requestToSend, requestToSendXOnXOff, xOnXOff)
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            // Set read/write timeouts
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
            //Set read/write timeout for gps port
            _serialPort_gps.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort_gps.WriteTimeout = 500;
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                
                try
                {
                    // Open the serial port
                    Console.WriteLine("Trying to open port");
                   // _serialPort.Open();
                    _serialPort.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Serial port connected.");
                    // Read data from the serial port
                                                            
                    string response1 = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                    //response1 = response1.Trim();
                    Console.WriteLine(" GPS Location: " + response1);
                    }
                    //OPEN Seriel_PORT_READING + DDMMYYYHHMMSS 

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error catching");
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // Close the serial port
                        if (_serialPort.IsOpen) 
                        {
                            _serialPort.Close();
                            Console.WriteLine("Serial port closed.");
                        }
                    }
                }
        Console.WriteLine("Execution Completed.Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

Output:
Iteration: 1

Current Reading Time: 4/30/2024 9:18:02 PM

Trying to open port

Serial port connected.

GPS Location: ?b☺☻∟H??☻?→?↕@c☺????B?K:)↔?

Serial port closed.

Iteration: 2

Current Reading Time: 4/30/2024 9:18:02 PM

Trying to open port

Serial port connected.

GPS Location: 6,,32,18,236,14,44,40,240,,46,29,249,\*76

$GPGSV,4,4,14,48,32,246,,,48,131,\*7E

$GPGST,011803.50,52,,,,13,15,11\*76

$PELFID,Bad Elf GNSS Surveyor,BE-GPS-3300,2.1.47,9.0.0,006597,Bad Elf GNSS Surveyor\*65

Serial port closed.

Execution Completed.Press any key to exit...

PUTTY Reading
▒▒b▒b1▒▒        ▒$GPRMC,013218.50,A,2548.97809,N,08021.28967,W,1.131,,010524,,,A\*63

$GPGGA,013218.50,2548.97809,N,08021.28967,W,1,04,5.84,12.5,M,-26.3,M,,\*5E

$GPGSA,A,3,15,18,23,24,,,,,,,,,12.11,5.84,10.61\*04

$GPGSV,4,1,14,05,12,088,15,10,20,302,17,13,06,042,,15,35,038,12\*77

$GPGSV,4,2,14,18,85,329,13,23,44,333,24,24,56,101,30,27,09,309,\*70

$GPGSV,4,3,14,29,19,193,,32,22,241,17,44,40,240,,46,29,249,\*77

$GPGSV,4,4,14,48,32,246,,,48,131,\*7E

$GPGST,013218.50,56,,,,19,17,13\*7A


What are you asking us?
